# how to capture data from json?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a text in json format:

```
'{"Info":{"Result":"OK","ID":8840,"FamilyName":"book","Title":"A950","Model":"A-A","Name":"A 5","Img":"A950-A.png"}}'
```

how do I capture the "Img" field
I'm trying to `print(json.loads(response.text['Info']['Img']))`
but I get an error: `string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 2):

You're `json.loads()`ing the wrong thing.

At the moment you're trying to index the string as if it were already parsed into Python data structures and then passing the result into `json.loads()`:

```py
print(json.loads(response.text['Info']['Img']))
#                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead, parse the whole response as JSON and *then* index into it:

```py
print(json.loads(response.text)['Info']['Img'])
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: exactly, my inattention ((( thank you very much!